# Parsing a simple text file in python

Tags: python, file

I've the following text file taken from a `csv` file. The file is two long to be shown properly here, so here's the line info:
The file has `5` lines:
The 1st one starts in `ETIQUETAS`
The 2nd one stars in `RECURSOS`
The 3rd one starts in `DATOS CLIENTE Y PIEZA`
The 4th one starts in `Numero Referencia`,
The 5th and last one starts in `BRIDA Al`.

> ETIQUETAS:;;;;;;;;;START;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;END;;
>   RECURSOS:;;;;;;;;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;0;;Nota: 0
>   equivale a infinito, para decir que no existen recursos usar un numero
>   negativo 
> DATOS CLIENTE Y PIEZA;;;;PLAZOS   Y   PROCESOS;;;;;;;;;;hoja
>   de ruta;MU;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; 
> Numero Referencia;Descripcion
>   Referencia;Nombre Cliente;Codigo Cliente;PLAZO DE
>   ENTREGA;piezas;PROCESO;MATERIAL;stock;PROVEEDOR;tiempo ida
>   pulidor;pzas dia;TPO;tiempo vuelta pulidor;TIEMPO RECEPCION;CONTROL
>   CALIDAD DE ENTRADA;TIEMPO CONTROL CALIDAD DE ENTRADA;ALMACEN A (ANTES
>   DE ENTRAR
>   MAQUINA);GRANALLA;TPO;LIMPIADO;TPO;BRILLADO;TPO;;CARGA;MAQUINA;SOLTAR;control;EMPAQUETADO;ALMACENB;TIEMPO;
>   BRIDA Al;BRIDA Al;AEROGRAFICAS AHE,
>   S.A.;394;;;niquelado;aluminio;;;;matriz;;;5min;NO;;3dias;;;;;;;;1;1;1;;1;4D;;

I want to do two things:

1. Count the between `START` and `END` of the first line, both inclusive and save it as `TOTAL_NUMBERS`. This means if I've `START;;END` has to count 3; the `START` itself, the blank space between the two `;;` and the `END` itself. In the example of the test, `START;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;END` it has to count `22`.

What I've tried so far:

```
f = open("lt.csv", 'r')
array = []
for line in f:
    if 'START' in line:
        for i in line.split(";"):
            array.append(i)

i = 0
while i < len(array):
    if i == 'START':
        # START COUNTING, I DONT KNOW HOW TO CONTINUE
    i = i + 1
```

2.Check the file, go until the word `PROVEEDOR` appears, and save that word and the following `TOTAL_NUMBERS`(in the example, `22`) on an array.
This means it has to save:

```
final array = ['PROVEEDOR', 'tiempo ida pulidor', 'pzas dia, 'TPO', 'tiempo vuelta pulidor', 'TIEMPO RECEPCION', 'CONTROL CALIDAD DE ENTRADA', 'TIEMPO CONTROL CALIDAD DE ENTRADA, 'ALMACEN A (ANTES DE ENTRAR MAQUINA)', 'GRANALLA', 'TPO', 'LIMPIADO', 'TPO','BRILLADO','TPO','','CARGA', 'MAQUINA', 'SOLTAR', 'control', 'EMPAQUETADO', 'ALMACENB']
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second question is also marked as `1`, if somebody could fix this I would appreciate it.

Comment: What happened to the rest of the line after `ALMACENB;`, is it discarded? Are you always going to stop at `ALMACENB;`?

Comment: It starts always at `PROVEEDOR` and ends `TOTAL_NUMBERS` (in the example, `22`) words after. You have that writen in question #2. Thanks in advance, Burhan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the file is split into two lines; the first line with START and END and then a long line which needs to be parsed. This should work:

```
with open('somefile.txt') as f:
   first_row = next(f).strip().split(';')
   TOTAL_NUMBER = len(first_row[first_row.index('START'):first_row.index('END')+1])
   bits = ''.join(line.rstrip() for line in f).split(';')
   final_array = bits[bits.index('PROVEEDOR'):bits.index('PROVEEDOR')+TOTAL_NUMBER]
```

Comment: Thanks Burhan. I've tried your solution and `TOTAL_NUMBERS` gives me `27` instead of `22`. And the file has `5` lines. The 1st one starts in `ETIQUETAS`, the 2nd one stars in `RECURSOS`, the 3rd one starts in `DATOS CLIENTE Y PIEZA`, and the 4th one starts in `Numero Referencia`, and the 5th and last one starts in `BRIDA Al`.

Comment: Thanks Burhan! It shows the `22` now. The thing is that I've also a problem with the `bits = f.readlines().split(';')` line. It shows me an error: `ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data`. What's the problem with this? Thanks in advance.